# How can I install phpmyadmin in my beanstalk ec2 environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my Codeigniter app into aws beanstalk environment and then I created a RDS instance inside the environment. And I set the ingress rule into the RDS so as to allow the inbound traffic only from the beanstalk ec2 instance. 
And I have checked the mysql access to RDS instance from the ec2 through ssh and run the below command and all works fine there.
"mysql -h {RDS_Host} -P 3306 -u {RDS_Username} -p"
Now I want to access the RDS database using phpmyadmin which is installed in beanstalk ec2. So can anybody please explain about how to install and configure phpmyadmin in beanstalk ec2 instance so that I can access the RDS using that.

Note: I am using the EB CLI to deploy each versions of my app.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i setup my phpmyadmin on ELB instance:

1) Download PHPMyAdmin from official site: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
2) Unzip file in your dev directory (ex: yoururl.com/phpmyadmin)
3) Open the config.sample.inc.php, edit with your RDS credentials, save and rename to config.inc.php
4) Delete /setup dir
5) Deploy with the new archives
6) Be happy! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated